# Xpath expression for an element that has two child elements with the same name.

Tags: xml, xpath

> I need to figure out what the xpath expression is for all the sections that are co-taught by two instructors. I know how to get all the sections with an instructor child, but I'm lost on how to get all sections with more than one instructor child.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <courses>
      <course number="341" credits="4.0">
        <title>Data Structures</title>
        <section number="01" delivery="Classroom">
          <enrollment>15</enrollment>
          <room>EA244</room>
          <instructor>
            <first>Nicole</first>
            <last>Anderson</last>
          </instructor>
        </section>
        <section number="02" delivery="Online">
          <enrollment>10</enrollment>
          <instructor>
            <first>Nicole</first>
            <last>Anderson</last>
          </instructor>
          <instructor>
            <first>Chi-Cheng</first>
            <last>Lin</last>
          </instructor>
        </section>
        <section number="03" delivery="Classroom">
          <enrollment>12</enrollment>
          <room>SH102</room>
          <instructor>
            <first>Mark</first>
            <last>Funk</last>
          </instructor>
        </section>
      </course>
      <course number="368" credits="4.0">
          <title>Introduction to Bioinformatics</title>
        <section number="01" delivery="Classroom">
          <enrollment>9</enrollment>
          <room>AT102</room>
          <instructor>
            <first>Chi-Cheng</first>
            <last>Lin</last>
          </instructor>
          <instructor>
            <first>Mingrui</first>
            <last>Zhang</last>
          </instructor>
        </section>
      </course>
      <course number="375" credits="4.0">
          <title>Computer Systems</title>
        <section number="01" delivery="ITV">
          <enrollment>18</enrollment>
                <room>EA244</room>
          <instructor>
            <first>Chi-Cheng</first>
            <last>Lin</last>
          </instructor>
        </section>
      </course>
      <course number="385" credits="3.0">
          <title>Applied Database Management Systems</title>
        <section number="01" delivery="Classroom">
          <enrollment>26</enrollment>
                <room>ST108</room>
          <instructor>
            <first>Nicole</first>
            <last>Anderson</last>
          </instructor>
        </section>
      </course>
      <course number="413" credits="3.0">
          <title>Advanced Networking</title>
        <section number="01" delivery="Online">
          <enrollment>10</enrollment>
          <instructor>
            <first>Chi-Cheng</first>
            <last>Lin</last>
          </instructor>
        </section>
      </course>
    </courses>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `//section[instructor[2]]` or `//section[count(instructor) > 1]`.